# plugin to print reports right to printer in grails

Tags: grails

I have no background printing reports others than when I use to use crystal report in small Visual Basic applications, now I am starting using grails and I need to print some reports in some pages with fixed constraints like receipt, I search in plug-ins but I do not know which one is the recommended one in this scenario

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rendering plugin can create PDF files from gsp code.  The PDFs can then be saved or printed as a report.

http://grails.org/plugin/rendering

Also a Jasper Reports plugin exists but I have not used that but that might fit your needs better.

http://grails.org/plugin/jasper

Comment: its look like the right direction, sadly poor documentation for newbies in jasper ireport designe.